What is the proof that the Schwarzschild metric is not static inside the horizon?
In Lecture Notes on General Relativity, Sean M. Carroll shows that the Schwarzschild metric is not only stationary but also static (Chapter 7, page 169, Eq. 7.20 and following interpretation). On the other hand, in reply on Physics, Ben Crowell says that the Schwarzschild metric is not static inside the horizon. How is this to be understood?

The reason is because the killing vector field $k=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ which is given by $k=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, is not timelike anymore for $r<2M$.

@P-A You are right, but the metric was derived under the assumption that it is static for all $r\in(0,\infty)$. This is what still puzzles me.

Birkhoffs theorem exactly tells us that such an assumption is not necessary. So I don't follow. Even the derivation for the Schwarzschild geometry outside of a star, using the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff equations, yields only a solution for $r>2M$.

If you solve Einstein's field equations for static spherically symmetric spacetime (see here) without matter, you get $g_{tt}=1+c/r$ and $g_{rr}=g_{tt}^{-1}$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. As you can see, the metric does not depend on time. So how can the solution of an elliptic equation become time dependent in some range of the variable $r$? This would require a hyperbolic equation.

FYI the reply you linked to was not posted by Sean Carroll.  Your question seems to imply that it was.

@MichaelSeifert You are right, my fault, sorry.

@P-A Birkhoff's theorem states that any spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum field equations must be static and asymptotically flat. This means that the exterior solution (i.e. the spacetime outside of a spherical, nonrotating, gravitating body) must be given by the Schwarzschild metric.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)   The exterior solution is not confined to R <2M.

@KDP I cannot find your last sentence in this link. Is it your conclusion?

@JanG yes.. The Schwarzschild solution, taken to be valid for all r > 0, is called a Schwarzschild black hole. It is a perfectly valid solution of the Einstein field equations, although (like other black holes) it has rather bizarre properties. Same link

@KDP I am fully aware of how it is taken. My need for clarification was just about how to interpret the time dependence in the $r<r_S$ region.

As @John Rennie’s answer says, in order to have a static (region of) spacetime, you first need a timelike Killing field (in that region) which satisfies the extra condition of having an involutive orthogonal distribution (equivalently, the orthogonal distribution must be Frobenius-integrable).
The problem is that the black hole region doesn’t even have any timelike Killing fields, so it cannot be stationary, let alone static. One indication for this is that the coordinate vector field $\partial_t$ is now spacelike  rather than timelike, however this does not imply that the black hole region is not stationary/static. There could be some other willy-wonka timelike Killing vector field in the black hole (but perhaps such that it becomes spacelike outside). Well, this actually does not happen, but we need to prove this (I won’t do it here though).
For notation sake, let $M=E\cup H\cup B$ be the smooth spacetime consisting of the Schwarzschild exterior, the horizon and the black hole region. The we have the following results the proof of which you can find in Barrett O’Neill’s Semi-Riemannian Geometry with Applications to Relativity (an excellent book with very clear treatment of the basics of Schwarzschild and FRW spacetimes):

$\xi$ is a Killing vector field on the exterior $E$ if and only if it equals $a\partial_t+\sigma$ for some constant $a$ and some vector field $\sigma$ which is the vertical lift of a Killing vector field on the round sphere $S^2$. In particular, the only timelikelike Killing vector fields on $E$ are non-zero constant multiples of $\partial_t$.
$\xi$ is a Killing vector field in the black hole $B$ if and only if it equals $a\partial_t+\sigma$ for some constant $a$ and some vector field $\sigma$ which is the vertical lift of a Killing vector field on the round sphere $S^2$. In particular, every Killing vector field on $B$ is spacelike.
$\xi$ is a Killing vector field in the black hole $B$ if and only if it equals $aT+\sigma$ for some constant $a$ and some vector field $\sigma$ which is the vertical lift of a Killing vector field on the round sphere $S^2$ (here $T=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ in Eddington-Finkelstein coordinates, which makes sense on all of $M$, and it restricts to the usual $\partial_t$ on $E$).

Note that the “if” direction is very easy and obvious; the “only if” direction is the more non-trivial one (it’s not entirely trivial because solving for $\xi$ such that $L_{\xi}g=0$ is actually a PDE, but a clever use of the various symmetries of Schwarzschild allows us the simplify the calculations). Also, you can’t really deduce statements 1 and 2 from each other unless you have some other fancy result about extending Killing vector fields from $E$ to $E\cup B$ or from $B$ to $E\cup B$ respectively; hence why I listed these two statements separately. Finally, statement 3 follows immediately from (1) or (2) and the fact that $(M,g)$ is a real-analytic Lorentzian manifold, so the result follows trivially by uniqueness of analytic continuation.
Note that for your question, it is only statement (2) that matters (I included the rest just for fun). All Killing vector fields on $B$ are spacelike, and so in particular none are timelike, hence $B$ is not stationary, and hence not static.

This is more than I was hoping for. I will read it carefully and then maybe ask some questions, thanks.

I still studying it. By the way, Cantor showed that there is a bijection between the interval $I=[0,1]$ and the n-fold product $I^n$. This means that a space-filling function is a bijection from the unit line segment to the unit square, cube or hypercube. I suppose it also means that the space part of $B$ can be completely represented by the region $H$, which is a two-sphere.  Interestingly, the function of the unit line segment is continuous, while its inverse function is not. This asymmetry could be the mathematical explanation of the black hole entropy inequality.

Your argument of time becoming space breaks down when switching to appropriate coordinates, but nevertheless +1 because your answer still explains how this misconception came into place.

@Yukterez which part of my answer specifically are you referring to that breaks down? Because I don’t think I wrote anything incorrect here.

@JanG umm Cantor’s works are not really relevant here and certainly has nothing to do with black hole entropy; Cantor’s work essentially shows that one ought to be careful when talking about sets and sizes. And yes there exist space-filling continuous curves but also that’s not relevant here; in fact Sard’s theorem shows that there is no $C^{\infty}$ analogue of a space-filling curve. And also it’s not true that $H$ is a $2$-sphere (and I never said it was), so I’m not sure what you mean there.

@peek-a-boo Right, it is not relevant to the questions here. I just wanted to learn what you think about such an idea it.

@peek-a-boo Sean M. Carroll in Lecture Notes on General Relativity writes: “Spherically symmetric” means “having the same symmetries as a sphere.” (In this
section the word “sphere” means $S^2$, not spheres of higher dimension.) Is he wrong?

@JanG I have no issues with what Carroll says, I just don’t see how that’s relevant here. You seem to be drawing connections where they don’t exist :) Here the future event horizon $H$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2\times\Bbb{R}$ (I excluded the bifurcate sphere in my definition of $H$; if we included it, we’d get something diffeomorphic to $S^2\times [0,\infty)$).

and btw the answer you linked to is not Carroll’s, but by Ben Crowell.

@peek-a-boo - I didn't say your answer was incorrect, I even upvoted it since according to the definition you use this is the logical consequence. In the more direct definition which I prefer: "In general relativity, a spacetime is said to be static if it does not change over time and is also irrotational" the meaning of the law is that it doesn't make a difference when you make your experiment, while in your more lawyer-like interpretation the sign flip of the covariant gtt and grr play the more important role, but I don't think that was in the spirit of the inventor.

@peek-a-boo Upps! Thanks for correction. My reference to the event horizon as $S^2$ was due to my attempts to consider the static spherical symmetry spacetime as fiber bundle, like I have found it in Kuenzle's paper.


Formally, a spacetime is static if it admits a global, non-vanishing, timelike Killing vector field $K$, which is irrotational, i.e., whose orthogonal distribution is involutive.

(source Wikipedia)
Outside the horizon the $t$ coordinate gives the timelike Killing field $\partial_t$, but inside the horizon the $t$ coordinate is spacelike not timelike so there is no timelike Killing field. Hence the interior is not static.

while it’s true there is no timelike Killing field in the black hole region $B$, the reason given here is not the full explanation. This only rules out the possibility that the extension of the usual $T=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is spacelike, but it says nothing about whether or not there could be some other timelike Killing field inside. Perhaps you’re already deeming this to be obvious, but to be explicit, the usual way to argue this is to first classify all Killing fields:

a vector field $\xi$ on the black hole region $B$ (or the Schwarzschild exterior, for that matter) is Killing if and only if it can be expressed as $a\partial_t+\sigma$ for some constant $a$ and for for some vector field $\sigma$ which is the vertical lift of a Killing field on the round sphere $S^2$. With this classification at hand, one can then conclude that every Killing field on $B$ is spacelike, and so there are no timelike ones, let alone timelike ones whose orthogonal distribution is involutive.

@peek-a-boo you should add that as a second answer. I'll upvote it!

@peek-a-boo Please do it.

John Rennie Renny, no offense, but Wikipedia is not a reliable source for me. For example, it says about gravitational singularity: "Gravitational singularities are ... where the density at the center of a black hole would become infinite ...". In the Schwarzschild interior solution, the (energy) density is finite. It is the pressure that becomes infinite.

@JanG You'll find that definition of static in any GR text. I linked Wikipedia simply because it was convenient.

@JanG Is there a dimension allowing for this pressure?

@Wookie I am not quite sure what you mean.

John Rennie Understandable, but Physics Stack Exchange is much better ;-)

Even in the classic Schwarzschild-Droste coordinates the metric is independent of the coordinate time t, but since that t is just the proper time of a stationary observer at infinity it might be more convincing to transform to coordinates that use the time coordinate of free-falling (Gullstrand-Painlevé) or proper-accelerating (Eddington-Finkelstein) local observers.
Then you will find that the metric is still independent of time, meaning it doesn't make a difference when you jump into the black hole. It will always take you the same amount of proper time to fall from one position to an other, you will encounter the same tidal forces at any given position on your way, and all the other invariants will also be the same.
It seems to me that the argument that the Schwarzschild metric wasn't static inside builds on either an overzealous definition of the word static, or even a misconception about coordinates.
The classic coordinates where the sign flip occurs use accelerated tachyons as local observers inside the horizon since those are the only ones capable of staying stationary with respect to the fixed stars outside and the singularity inside, so in that sense it is only natural that the time coordinate of the fixed stars is spacelike to them.
Before the proper coordinate transformations were discovered that used to be a common misconception, but nowadays we know the structure of spacetime doesn't change abruptly at the horizon, since as you cross it everything is smooth and you notice nothing special, at least from the relativistic perspective.
If we ain't talking about an eternal Schwarzschild but an astrophysical black hole formed by a collapsing star as described by the Oppenheimer-Snyder metric we have a different story though, in that case the interior is not the usual static vacuum solution but that of collapsing matter, which is locally dynamic, although still frozen due to time dilation from the outside perspective.

Your answer forces me to reconsider many of my views about the BH (+1). By the way, why do we physicists care about the eternal black hole at all? It is like trying to extrapolate the world lines of the astronaut into the beyond after they have ended in our world. However, it never happened. We were never there ( the motto of the submarine crew in "Dark Transit" by Michael DiMercurio). :-)
